# Mysql->PHP->Java - How to avoid losing information in strings?

Tags: java, php, mysql, string-parsing

I am trying to make an android app, and I am using some userbased input from mysql. I output it with php and load it with java.

There can be plenty of results.

At the moment my output could be.

IDS: 1,4,7,3,9
MSG ffsdf,sdfs,dfsd,fsdfsdf,sdfsfd

But if people write a `,` or or something in their text my code will fail.

Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: Validate user input? use a delimiter that can't occur in the data? quote items containing commas?

Comment: My friend keep telling me thats stupid.

Comment: I suspect those suggestions are not the stupid thing here.

Comment: Well then ask your friend what's not stupid if she/he is so clever.

Comment: Tabs and tilde ("~") appear to be popular alternatives for delimiters.  Otherwise, you could always go retro and do segment positioning where characters 1-40 is field one, characters 41-80 is field two, etc.  That gets real fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use this approach (delimiters). why don't you create separate variable for each item (easy to do via XML in android). This way you have a better control, there's no need to parse anything and you can easily add validations!